# Расположение MarkerInfoWindow в osmdroid

Tags: android, marker, infowindow

Использую OsmDroid 6.0.2

Унаследовал класс от **MarkerInfoWindow** и при создании маркера задаю **InfoWindow** этому маркеру.

1. При клике на маркер, **InfoWindow** открывается за границей
   видимости.
2. При свайпе по карте **InfoWindow** не перемещается с маркером (как
   это сделано в MapView от Google) - такого нету из коробки?

Можете подсказать, как исправить эти недочеты?

**up:**

Решение для №1 такое:

```
private Marker.OnMarkerClickListener onMarkerClickListener = new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            Point markerPoint = projection.toPixels(marker.getPosition(), null);
            Point targetPoint = new Point(markerPoint.x, markerPoint.y - getView().getHeight() / 3);
            IGeoPoint targetGeoPoint = projection.fromPixels(targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y);
            mapController.animateTo(targetGeoPoint);
           // marker.showInfoWindow();
            return false;
        }
    };

marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(onMarkerClickListener);
```

А вот решение для второго я не нашел. Ни кто не хочет помощь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение для первого

```
private Marker.OnMarkerClickListener onMarkerClickListener = new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            Point markerPoint = projection.toPixels(marker.getPosition(), null);
            Point targetPoint = new Point(markerPoint.x, markerPoint.y - getView().getHeight() / 3);
            IGeoPoint targetGeoPoint = projection.fromPixels(targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y);
            mapController.animateTo(targetGeoPoint);
           // marker.showInfoWindow();
            return false;
        }
    };

marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(onMarkerClickListener);
```

Решение второго

```
mapView.addMapListener(new MapListener() {
            public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent zoom) {

                return false;
            }

            public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent arg0) {
                ArrayList<InfoWindow> infoWindows = InfoWindow.getOpenedInfoWindowsOn(mapView);
                if (infoWindows != null && infoWindows.size() > 0){
                    for (InfoWindow window : infoWindows){
                        window.draw();
                    }
                }

                //InfoWindow.closeAllInfoWindowsOn(mapView);
                return false;
            }
        } );
```